# Which transmission oil should I use?

Tags: manual-transmission, audi, a3

I'm the third owner of an **Audi A3 2001 1.9TDI** with **5-gear manual transmission**. I'd refer to the owners manual but I didn't get it when I bought the car, someone must have misplaced it. I can't find much information online.

Comment: Have you got a workshop manual for it (Haynes or similar) - they usually give the requirements for all the fluids, and can be found cheaply online if you don't already have one

Comment: A quick google search found : http://audiworkshopmanual.blogspot.ch/2013/07/audi-a3s3-workshop-manuals.html

Comment: An auto parts store or the dealership should be able to look that up for you.

Answer (score 3):

We didn't get to enjoy the A3 diesel in the states, but every other Audi manual trans from that era that I can look up uses:

Synthetic SAE 75w/90 Gear Oil

Audi Part Number G 005 000